# get recently logged project list using cookies javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

After login into my application, it will redirect to the project list page. in their user need to select a project and will navigate to the dashboard. When users come back to the project list page I need to have the recently selected project numbers sorted according to date. I'm tried to use a cookie and get the project id. But I was not able to complete it. Please let me know if anyone has a solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var projects = [{
    name: "Project 001",
    id: 102,
    detaild: "test details"
  }, {
    name: "Project 002",
    id: 103,
    detaild: "test details"
  }, {
    name: "Project 002",
    id: 104,
    detaild: "test details"
  }, {
    name: "Project 003",
    id: 105,
    detaild: "test details"
  }, {
    name: "Project 004",
    id: 106,
    detaild: "test details"
  }, ]

  $.each(projects, function(key, project) {
    var studyTileHtml = `<div class="project-tile" data-id="` + project.id + `"> <p> Project Name: ` + project.name + `</p><p> Project Id: ` + project.id + `</p> <p> Project Details: ` + project.detaild + `</p>  </div>`;
    $('.project-list').append(studyTileHtml);
  });

  $('.project-tile').click(function(event) {
    var expires = "",
      days = 30;

    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    $('.recent-list').append($(this).attr('data-id'));

    document.cookie = "loggedId" + "=" + ($(this).attr('data-id') || "") + expires + "; path=/";
    //window.location.href = '/dashbord';
  });
});
```

```css
.project-tile {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #969696;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.recent-log {
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-list"> </div>

<div class="recent-log">
  <h2> Recent logged list</h2>
  <div class="recent-list"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @rory Any idea on this